# Does the category of sheaves have enough injectives?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal F$ a sheaf of a category $C$ over some space $X$. There is an injection $$\mathcal F \hookrightarrow \Pi_{x\in X} \ \mathcal F_x.$$
It seems like if the category $C$ has enough injectives, then we can inject each stalk $\mathcal F_x$in a injective object $I_x \in C$ and thus we get an injection of sheaves:
$$\mathcal F \hookrightarrow \Pi_{x\in X}\ \mathcal F_x\hookrightarrow \Pi_{x\in X} \ I_x.$$

Is this true? Further question, do the categories one usually works with have enough injectives? For example Abelian groups, $\mathcal O_X$-modules etc...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is called the Godement resolution. For abelian groups there are always enough injective (because injective $\Leftrightarrow$ divisible). For quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-modules, this is true if $X$ is noetherian. This is not true for coherent sheaves however, so this is why we need quasi-coherent sheaves.

Comment: Enlarging the question: what about categories of categories such as _Cat_ (the category of all small categories)?